# How to regenerate the icon of android project in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

When I new an Android project, I was able to generate different size of the app icon by giving an image or a text, how can I do this to a project which is under development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click your project in packeage exploler.
New-> other -> Android Icon Set

Select Launcher Icons and click next.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Launcher Icon Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html) from the ANDROID ASSET STUDIO